# Is it possible to Upload multiple Document in object document checklist item and to store data in related list in Financial service cloud. Provide Sol

Tags: salesforce, fsc

Is it possible to Upload multiple Document in object  document checklist item and to store data in related list in Financial service cloud.
Need to know process how to do it. How to do this for multiple Document in single click approch.